# Is this absorption law if not by what rule is it simplified?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0as464WmfCo it is mentioned that the following is simplified via the "absorption" law:
$$A + \widehat{A}B = A + B.$$

However https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWU1mGCT_34 at around 4:40 it states this is not an example of the absorption law.

So by what rule is the above simplified (assuming the first video had it correct)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not the absorption law, it is the distributive law, followed by complementation:

$$\begin{align}
A + \overline{A}B & = (A+\overline{A})(A+B) \\
 & = 1(A+B)\\ 
 & = A+B 
\end{align}$$